# How to change from Python to PyPy to compile ROS Node?

Tags: ros, rospackage

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a package where the nodes are written in python using rospy and other python modules. But lately i realized that PyPy is a better alternative than the default python interpreter.

Basically, i want to change the interpreter such that when I run
"rosrun pkg_name node_name", it will run using the PyPy interpreter instead of the Python Interpreter. I am guessing that this might be possible if I make some changes in the CMakeLists.txt file. Any help ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/243431/how-to-change-from-python-to-pypy-to-compile-ros-node-?/) by [siddian93](https://answers.ros.org/users/27916/siddian93/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2016-09-09

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Given that significant parts of the ROS libraries use the cpython API, this would necessitate a significant rewrite to use pypy.

(See http://answers.ros.org/question/66065/using-pypy-with-ros-for-better-performance/ )

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-12-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0